# Is the Penny Arcade adventure preceding Storm Tower published?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures

In 2008, Christopher Perkins ran an adventure with four players, named *"Penny Arcade and the Tower of Storms"*. The adventure was recorded as season 2 of [the Penny Arcade podcasts](https://web.archive.org/web/20140802191048/https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/podcasts/acquisitions-inc), and in the following year made into a published adventure under the name [Storm Tower](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106182713/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20090513).

The prequel to this, however - season one, featuring Jim Darkmagic, Binwin Bronzebottom, and Omin as Acquisitions Incoporated - was an adventure for three players. According to the author's notes in *Storm Tower*, it was an abridged version of the *Keep on the Shadowfell* adventure. By "abridged", they mean it was *heavily* modified and streamlined.

Was the prequel adventure ever made available in some form where I could pick it up and run it for *my* players?

*As a side note: I'm keen on the three-player adventure because I have three players, not four, and don't have the experience necessary to confidently retune the four-player campaign for three players.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the updated, free version of the module is about as close as you're going to get.  [It's available here](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/110212/H1-Keep-on-the-Shadowfell--QuickStart-Rules-4e).

Unless you are time constrained as Chris Perkins and James Wyatt were (which meant they cut straight to the Keep itself and had each level only have 1 or 2 encounters), the only real change you'll need to make is to scale the adventure.  The adventure is actually tuned for 5 PCs by default.  So your XP budget will be about 60% of what's in the adventure which can usually be eyeballed by taking out a couple monsters.  There's plenty of information out there for scaling 4E encounters.  I found [tools like this one](http://www.kassoon.com/dnd/encounter-builder/) quite helpful in tuning my own adventures.

There's been a couple people who have revised the module as a whole so that its plot is more cohesive.  [Justin Alexander's](http://www.thealexandrian.net/creations/keep-shadowfell/kots-dm.pdf) and [Myrhdraak's](http://web.comhem.se/mwester/Shadowfell/Documents/H1-H3_Orcus_Conversion.pdf) are two that I have found interesting.  Of note, Myrhdraak's also modifies the other two published Heroic tier adventures as well.  You might check those out to see if they are more to your liking, but you'll face similar scaling issues with them.

Comment: "It's available here" link is broken. I realize this is nine years old.

Comment: Quite right.  It is available via DMGuild (https://www.dmsguild.com/product/110212/H1-Keep-on-the-Shadowfell--QuickStart-Rules-4e) for the low price of free.

Comment: @Granger44: You should edit that updated link into your post instead.

Comment: Done...I wasn't in a position to edit the full answer, so wanted to get a comment out quickly so people could find it over the US Holiday weekend.